# vertical alignment of text with slides class

Tags: vertical-alignment, presentations

I would like the content of each slide to be aligned at 
the top of each slide. How can one achieve that? By default
the text is centered vertically, and that looks sloppy.

There are many answers about how to do it
in with `beamer` package, but I am using the plain simple `slides` 
class because I don't need the wealth of `beamer`'s features.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\let\@topfil\relax
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{slides}

\makeatletter
\let\@topfil\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This text is not centered in the page
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]